# How to parse xml string in windows phone 8

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, https, xml-parsing

I am getting correctly xml from web service but I am unable to parse it. I tried different methods i-e XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml_string); and etc but I get exceptions
May be it needs something extra due to secure connection
here is the code

```
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(new Uri("https://services.sunopps.com/auth?username=******&password=******"));

try
{
    WebResponse resp = await req.GetResponseAsync();
    Stream respStream = resp.GetResponseStream();

    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(respStream);
    string xml_string = sr.ReadToEnd();
     // Exception occurrs on .Parse
     //XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml_string);
}
catch (XmlException e)
{
    target.Text = e.Message;
}
```

Comment: So what does the exception say?

Comment: if i use XDocument.parse then
data at the root level is invalid. line 1 position 1

Comment: @ZaheerMehmood Assuming you deleted the question only to hide the login data: The old revisions are removed now so I've undeleted the question. You need to change your password nonetheless. If you want the question deleted again for another reason feel free to do so.

Comment: Obviously the received response is not a valid XML. Nobody will be able to give you the answer without seeing the response.